# eventid 11156 registered with some errors

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2003, rdp

Got this error when I started my windows 2003 server

[image]

When I saw the event viewer I got message as "The system failed to register pointer (PTR) resource records for the network adapter....." with **event-id=11156**

Because of this my RDP to server is not happening. This happened suddenly and my other servers in the network connected to the same DC is working absolutely fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a network issue between that system and the DNS server, which is also why RDP is failing

Comment: But it's a vmware virtual network(network adapter). It should affect other server also. Restarting the server did not help

Comment: Make sure the Nic is connected.

Answer (score 0):

The PTR record is of no great concern: it's only used to lookup names based on IP addresses and have no effect on RDP connection so it's not the cause of your problem. (However,you might want to have a look at the standard [answer from MS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc735750%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) regarding this event and how to investigate it).

You should try a standard network diag (in this order):

- Do I have DNS resolution ? (`nslookup myserver.mydomain.org`)
- Do I have a working network path ? (`ping myserver.mydomain.org`)
- Can I connect to the remote server's RDP port (`telnet 3389`)
- Does local logon at the server's console work ?

Comment: 1) yes DNS resolved
2) ping is hapening
3)telnet localhost and from other servers-connecting
4) Yes I am using console itself to check all these

Comment: tried ipconfig /registerdns. It again gives the same error in the event log

Comment: What is the problem you're seeing with RDP ?

Comment: I am getting the usual error message- "remote desktop can't connect to the remote computer for one of these......"

Comment: You haven't performed the telnet connection test: don't connect to or from localhost (RDP won't work on the loopback anyway) but do it from the machine you're trying to connect from.

Comment: ya I am able to telnet from other servers in the network. I checked all the services and other properties, everything is same as other servers

Comment: Just now got this error in the event log- "The RDP protocol component X.224 detected an error in the protocol stream and has disconnected the client" event-Id=50